# Jenkins pipeline with polling triggers multiple times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've created a number of script syntax Jenkinsfiles with this header:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    ])
])
```

They almost always trigger at least twice for every commit. Once within 5 minutes of the commit, and again at +5 minutes from the first build. The builds are shorter than 5 minutes long, meaning the second build triggers after the first build has completed. Jenkins log shows both triggers as being identical, as though the second build is not aware of the first build.

I don't understand how this isn't a larger issue. It makes continuous deployment extremely dangerous. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `H/5 * * * *` -> `H` means run in the next 5 mins whenever is possible. So if the build was run at 1st minute of the hour, second one may run at 6th-10th min whenever possible (Considers other jobs are running or not). And you didn't mention anything about stopping the concurrent builds also. So it will run as per your configuration.

You can stop building multiple parallel by adding this to your script.

```
options { disableConcurrentBuilds() }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't explain the behavior I am seeing. Here's an example timeline:

`12:00 - commit pushed
12:03 - build 1 starts
12:05 - build 1 finishes
12:07 - build 2 starts`

It doesn't make any sense that two builds are triggered for a single commit

Comment: [https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40722](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40722) Please look at this thread once.

Comment: Well this is incredibly confusing, but you've put me on the right track. This:

"If you want SCM polling, you should have the scan run at the polling interval as the scan will do one efficient scan for all branches rather than having each branch scan."

is a pretty good clue. I disabled project scanning, and the double builds stopped happening. But now the project doesn't update with new branches.

Will require further research.